# Estimating temperature with Boltzmann relation with split emission lines

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, plasma-physics, photon-emission

I'm trying to estimate the temperature of a plasma through the use of hydrogen lines, $H_{\alpha}$ and $H_{\beta}$ using the Boltzmann relation:

$$ \frac{ n_{2} }{ n_{1} } =  \frac{ g_{2} }{ g_{1} }e^{ \frac{-\big( E_{2} -  E_{1} \big) }{ k_{b}  T_{e} } } $$

I have measured both with a spectrometer, and was able to resolve the $H_{\alpha}$ line well enough to see fine structure, splitting the line in two.

My question is, when I am using the Boltzmann relation, do I use one or the other lines of the $H_{\alpha}$ doublet or the sum of them?  And, if it's the sum, should I use the sum of the peak heights, or the sum of the areas?  Since the intensity is equal to the product of density $n$, partition weight function $g$, and the Einstein coefficient $A$ so $I = n*g*A$, I'm not sure how to properly determine $I$ and how to use it in the Boltzmann relation.

Comment: Have you looked at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_diode_laser_absorption_spectroscopy)?  Also, have you tried looking into [thermal Doppler broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_broadening)?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks, but I'm not sure I follow.  Aren't line broadening and splitting two different things?  The splitting in my work comes from fine structure, so I don't see how thermal broadening is involved.

Comment: I thought you were looking for the temperature of the plasma.  So I thought that the width of the line relative to it's "cold" width would help provide that information, would it not?

Comment: @honeste_vivere I think you are right, however, as I understand it, using line ratios causes any wavelength-dependence and geometric effects to cancel out, which I think would give the most accurate measure.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are advantages to both methods.  The downside for both is that the simplest (and most predominantly used) models assume Maxwellian velocity distribution functions (VDFs), which is not always valid (e.g., solar observations showed that a kappa VDFs were much better at modeling the emission lines).  In your case, if this is a lab plasma a Maxwellian VDF might be okay...

Comment: 1) Why is there an $e$ in the exponent.  2)  I think this is addressed in the book _Radiative Processes in Astrophysics_ by Rybicki and Lightman in pages 359-370 (or somewhere around there).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Fixed it!

Comment: @honeste_vivere I checked Rybicki & Lightman but couldn't find anything on how to use split lines for a Boltzmann temperature estimate.  I have the 2004 version, perhaps it's elsewhere?

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd...  It looks like my 1st edition [(c)1979] has a bunch of stuff on this in the back of the book answers to problem 9.2, which is between pages 359-370 in my version.  Perhaps they have a solution to a different problem in the newer version...

Comment: @honeste_vivere In the 2nd edition, problem 9.2 is on page 264, and is about writing out the correct spectroscopic terms given configurations and L-S coupling... nothing about the Boltzmann relation, lines, splitting, etc.  The solution to 9.2 is on page 359, but again says nothing about Boltzmann relation, lines, splitting, etc.  Perhaps we are talking about two different things?

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry... There are comments about this (at varying levels of relevance) in answers to problems 9.4, 9.5, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, and 11.1.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I'm not seeing anything about line ratios for split emission lines in any of those problems in the 2004 edition.  I couldn't find this issue anywhere in the book at all.